# While creating StorageManager client , getting "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.doAfterResponseSuccess"

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, reactor-netty

code snippet:

```
profile = new AzureProfile(tenantId, subId, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

    credential =
        new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .authorityHost(profile.getEnvironment().getActiveDirectoryEndpoint())
            .tenantId(tenantId)
            .build();

    manager = StorageManager.authenticate(credential, profile);
```

dependencies used :

```
compile group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-core-management', version: '1.1.0'
    compile group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-identity', version: '1.2.2'
    compile group: 'com.azure.resourcemanager', name: 'azure-resourcemanager-storage', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-core', version: '3.4.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.13.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0'
    compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'adal4j', version: '1.6.6'
  compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-client-authentication', version: '1.4.0'

spring version : 2.1.18.RELEASE
```

while creating a StorageManager instance, getting the following error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.doAfterResponseSuccess(Ljava/util/function/BiConsumer;)Lreactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient;
    at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder.build(NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder.java:101) ~[azure-core-http-netty-1.7.1.jar!/:?]
    at com.azure.core.http.netty.implementation.ReactorNettyClientProvider.createInstance(ReactorNettyClientProvider.java:14) ~[azure-core-http-netty-1.7.1.jar!/:?]
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.HttpClientProviders.createInstance(HttpClientProviders.java:39) ~[azure-core-1.12.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpClient.createDefault(HttpClient.java:39) ~[azure-core-1.12.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipelineBuilder.build(HttpPipelineBuilder.java:60) ~[azure-core-1.12.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.azure.resourcemanager.resources.fluentcore.utils.HttpPipelineProvider.buildHttpPipeline(HttpPipelineProvider.java:85) ~[azure-resourcemanager-resources-2.1.0.jar!/:2.1.0]
    at com.azure.resourcemanager.resources.fluentcore.utils.HttpPipelineProvider.buildHttpPipeline(HttpPipelineProvider.java:45) ~[azure-resourcemanager-resources-2.1.0.jar!/:2.1.0]
    at com.azure.resourcemanager.storage.StorageManager.authenticate(StorageManager.java:55) ~[azure-resourcemanager-storage-2.1.0.jar!/:2.1.0]
```

when ran the same code from local machine , its working fine , but when application is deployed , its giving this error, How to resolve this issue ??

Comment: The reactory netty version are same in your local machine and remote?

Comment: yes, same version on both

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?